# Error: Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)

Tags: python, api

I have a little code, in python 2.7.17, where I'm trying to reach the Yahoo! Finance API to get information about a stock, but when I execute it, I get an error. I don't know how to fix it.

This is the code:

```
 import urllib

urlStock = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=nagh' 
response = urllib.urlopen(urlStock).read()
print response
```

And this is the error:

```
   Exception has occurred: IOError
[Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)
  File "/Users/ivanparra/Dropbox/Aprendizaje Python/InternetTests.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = urllib.urlopen(urlStock).read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site has been discontinued for since 2018, unfortunately ([more discussion here](https://github.com/RxJSInAction/rxjs-in-action/issues/13)). However, there is an alternative, as pointed out on the linked Github issue thread. The URL is:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&symbols=AAPL&fields=regularMarketPrice
```

Personally, I tend to prefer using the `requests` library (which you can easily install with pip) whenever possible because of its simple syntax. If you have SSL issues, see my comment in the example code.

Here's how I'd query it:

```
import requests
import pdb

res = requests.get("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&symbols=AAPL&fields=regularMarketPrice")
# If you need to work around SSL issues, set the verify kw arg to False. For example:
# requests.get("URL_HERE", verify=False)

stock_data = res.json()
price = stock_data['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['regularMarketPrice']
print(price)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will prove it and I'll tell you.